# Can't access a azure active directory custom role in pay as you go subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I create a pay as you go subscription in azure port. And added a new user to azure port as a guest user. I want to change that guest user role as a Global administrator. So go to azure active directory and select the user and choose to add role option. But I can't access the add assignment option it is disabled.I'm the administer of this portal and I created the subscription west us. The same way I created the subscription in another account in south India and it shows active.how to enable the customer role assignment. 
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot about the role of your admin account and another screenshot about the assignment option is disabled. Generally, when your account is not a tenant administrator, "Add assignment" is disabled. So check the role of your admin account firstly.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot about the role of your admin account. You can find it by  clicking on your own admin account and select "Assigned roles". see https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvlDh.png.

Comment: Hi, any updates?

Comment: No .still in same state